Autofill color not changing or updating
I am just starting out in ASP.NET and following a tutorial im using the mvc project and I have a form in dark theme however when you autofill the form with chrome such as name and phone number. It changes the colours to a to where you cant see the text because its white on white and i have a dark theme. I have tried going into he css and changing it but when i inspect the website when i run the app the changes dont go through. I changed it to black so i can see the text, but when i run the project and inspect the page it still says white or #fff. How do i fix this? I also have another css linked and i have changed the same thing and still no fix.




Could this simply be a browser caching thing?

@UweKeim Not sure cant seem to fix it
